# Firebase function transaction failed: data returned Nan in property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions and I'm trying to update/increment value each time by request I send in the body.
that's my node in firebase

```
     "global-counters": {
    "1": "0",
    "2": "0",
    "3": "0"
  },
```

that's my function i wrote

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let answers = { '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0 }

exports.tryGetCount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(`req method ${req.method}`)    
    let userAnswer = req.body.answer;
    console.log(`user answer is ${userAnswer}`)
    let userInformation = req.body.userInfo;
    if (answers.hasOwnProperty(userAnswer)) {
         admin.database().ref('/global-counters').child(userAnswer).transaction(eventSnapshot => {
            let parseAnswer = parseInt(eventSnapshot)
            eventSnapshot = parseAnswer +1; // here i want to increment the value
            return eventSnapshot;
        }).then((e) => {
            return admin.database().ref('/questionsTest').child(userInformation.uid).set(userInformation).then((snapshot) => {
                return res.send({ snapshot: snapshot, answers:e})
            }).catch((e)=>{
                return res.status(400).json({error:e})
            })
        }).catch((e) => {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: e });
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'invalid property user answer' })
    }
});
```

that's the post http request i do

```
{
        "answer":"3",
        "userInfo":{
            "uid":"1239",
            "gid": "1",
            "qid":"2",
            "aid":"3"
        }
    }
```

what I want to do is, for example the user send

```
'answer':'3'
```

so i want to increment +1 the index '3' into firebase then save the user data in other node.

some issues i faced in:
first I get the error in functions logs
[image]

second, when I try to use with postman or any way to make request I get this error

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

when I change the functions this way

```
exports.tryGetCount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(`req method ${req.method}`)  
    console.info(req.body)  
    let userAnswer = req.body.answer;
    console.log(`user answer is ${userAnswer}`)
    console.log(`typeof is`,typeof userAnswer) // i get "type of string"
    let userInformation = req.body.userInfo;
    if (answers.hasOwnProperty(userAnswer)) {
         return admin.database().ref(`/global-counters/${userAnswer}`).transaction(eventSnapshot => {
            console.info(`event snapshot ${eventSnapshot}`)
            let parseAnswer = parseInt(eventSnapshot);
            eventSnapshot = parseAnswer +1;
            return eventSnapshot;
        }).then((e) => {
            return admin.database().ref('/questionsTest').child(userInformation.uid).set(userInformation).then((snapshot) => {
                return res.send({ snapshot: snapshot, answers:e})
            }).catch((e)=>{
                return res.status(400).json({error:e})
            })
        }).catch((e) => {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: e });
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'invalid property user answer' })
    }
});
```

so this way works alternately. e.g, I run it via postman, 3 of 4 trys, it not works it shows the error

> Error: could not handle the request

the last time I try, it works and return

```
{
"answers": {
    "committed": true,
    "snapshot": 4
}
```

}

Comment: What does `console.info(event snapshot ${eventSnapshot})` log out?

Comment: Sometimes it show the current value of the specific key im looking for and someti mes its null. I took screen video of this when it happen, if there any way to share, i will be happy to do that

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `parseInt` is failing to coerce eventSnapshot into a number which results in NaN which appears can't be stored in Firebase.  I would investigate what eventSnapshot is.  According to the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction), you are receiving an object which would cause the issue you are having.

> A developer-supplied function which will be passed the current data stored at this location (as a JavaScript object). The function should return the new value it would like written (as a JavaScript object). If undefined is returned (i.e. you return with no arguments) the transaction will be aborted and the data at this location will not be modified.

It is not clear to me if you are receiving a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val), the name `eventSnapshot` makes me think you are.  If that is the case, you would need to call `.val()` to get the JavaScript value.

Let me know if that doesn't work and I will try to replicate it on my end.

Comment: I try to make eventsnapshot.val() but I get the error@cannot read property 'val' of null
    at Object.admin.database.ref.child.transaction.eventSnapshot [as update] (/user_code/index.js:16:57)
    at Repo_1.Repo.startTransaction

Comment: when i console.info(eventSnapshot)  i get null.. Do i do something wrong?

Comment: Interesting, that means the result of that child/transaction call is not what you are expecting it to be.  So that makes sense why `parseInt` is returning a NaN.

Comment: Yes but its happened alternately.. sometimes ut return number and the request works fine but sometimes not and return Nan.. with same body params!

Comment: Hmm, I would check to make sure that your data structure looks correct after executing this function successfully.  In other words, make sure you are saving what you expect to be saving.  You can also implement a check that if the value is null, first time seeing it, set the value equal to 1.

Comment: Yes, i checked it.. any more idea?